# Facing error while running ng serve command

Tags: node.js, angular, angularjs, angular-material, node-modules

I am trying to run ng serve command for my project , i tried **npm i** command for many times, but it showing same error continously.
Node version is : v16.13.2
Npm version is : 8.4.1

[Image is of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtZUp.png)

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415134/error-node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-current-environment-windows-64-bit-w) helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Your Issue

The error you facing with running the application is issue with the SCSS compilation. Certain packages are missing related `scss`
Try - `npm rebuild node-sass --force`

If still doesn't work out, freshly recreate the project and follow standard installation of libraries related to `scss`.

Helping Link:

1. [Angular won't run my ng serve - Sass Loader error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58650303/angular-wont-run-my-ng-serve-sass-loader-error)
2. [Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324519/node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-current-environment-linux-64-bit-with-false)

### Standard Angular Issue Resolution

1. Delete `package-lock.json`.
2. Clear cache - `npm cache clean --force` **or** `npm cache clean -f`
3. Delete `node_modules` folder
4. Reinstall dependencies - `npm install`
5. Run the application - `ng serve`

Comment: npm rebuild node-sass --force not work for me. so i tried the standard angular issue resolution steps which you mention , but now i am getting error for npm install.

Comment: Then there isn't any problem with the `npm` or `node_modules`. It seems some imports are either deprecated or not resolved. I'll suggest to check with SASS support version and angular version's clashes on github.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps to resolve this issue which worked in my case.

1. Delete **`node-sass`** folder (..\ `AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass`), **`node-modules`** folder and **`package-lock.json`**
2. Clear cache - *`npm cache clean --force`*
3. Reinstall **`node-sass`** globally - *`npm i node-sass@4.13.1 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`*
4. Reinstall project dependencies - *`npm install -no-package-lock`*
5. Start application - *`ng serve`* or *`npm start`*

This should update your **`node-sass`** global version. (please update version that you need to have as per your project)

Comment: When i try npm i node-sass@4.14.1 command , then it is taking lots of time and after some time socket timeout This is a problem related to network connectivity. error display.